# Count the scale of a given decimal

Tags: powershell, decimal-precision

How can I count the scale of a given decimal in Powershell?

```
$a = 0.0001
$b = 0.000001
```

Casting `$a` to a string and returning `$a.Length` gives a result of 6...I need 4.

I thought there'd be a decimal or math function but I haven't found it and messing with a string seems inelegant.

Comment: This answer might help if you convert the C# code into PowerShell - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33490834/3156906. That deals with ```Decimal``` numbers though, not ```double``` which your example uses (```$b = 0.00001; write-host $b.GetType().FullName``` gives System.Double so I'm not sure how applicable it will be...)

Comment: i agree that it seems a math method otta exist. it likely _does_ ...but i can't find it. however, your string technique will work with a bit more work try this ... >>> `([double]0.0001).ToString().Split('.')[-1].Length` <<< that gives me `4`.

Comment: In case you're interested, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1212957) is the mathematic way to do it.

Comment: Good find, @mclayton, and good point that fractional number literals in PowerShell are `[double]` instances by default, but simply adding suffix `d` turns them into `[decimal]` (`0.00001d`); my answer now shows a PowerShell version of the linked C# solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably a better mathematic way but I'd find the decimal places like this:

```
$a = 0.0001
$decimalPlaces = ("$a" -split '\.')[-1].TrimEnd('0').Length
```

Basically, split the string on the `.` character and get the length of the last string in the array. Wrapping `$a` in double-quotes implicitly calls `.ToString()` with an invariant culture (you could expand this as `$a.ToString([CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)`), making this method to determine the number of decimal places culture-invariant.

`.TrimEnd('0')` is used in case `$a` were sourced from a string, not a proper number type, it's possible that trailing zeroes could be included that should not count as decimal places. However, if you want the *scale* and not just the used decimal places, leave `.TrimEnd('0')` off like so:

```
$decimalPlaces = ("$a" -split '\.')[-1].Length
```

Answer (score 2):

[mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton) helpfully linked to [this answer to a related C# question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33490834/45375) in a comment, and the solution there can indeed be adapted to PowerShell, **if working with or conversion to type `[decimal]` is acceptable**:

```
# Define $a as a [decimal] literal (suffix 'd')
# This internally records the scale (number of decimal places) as specified.
$a = 0.0001d 

# [decimal]::GetBits() allows extraction of the scale from the
# the internal representation:
[decimal]::GetBits($a)[-1] -shr 16 -band 0xFF # -> 4, the number of decimal places
```

<sup>The [`System.Decimal.GetBits` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.getbits#System_Decimal_GetBits_System_Decimal_) returns an array of internal bit fields whose last element contains the scale in bits 16 - 23 (8 bits, even though the max. scale allowed is `28`), which is what the above extracts.</sup>

Note: A PowerShell number literal that is a fractional number *without* the `d` suffix - e.g., `0.0001` becomes a `[double]` instance, i.e. a double-precision *binary* floating-point number.

PowerShell automatically converts `[double]` to `[decimal]` values on demand, but do note that there can be rounding errors due to the differing internal representations, and that `[double]` can store larger numbers than `[decimal]` can (although not accurately).

A **`[decimal]` literal - one with suffix `d`** (note that C# uses suffix `m`) - is **parsed with a scale *exactly as specified***, so that applying the above to `0.000d` and `0.010d` yields `3` in both cases; that is, the **trailing zeros *are* meaningful**.

This does *not* apply if you (implicitly) convert from `[double]` instances such as `0.000` and `0.010`, for which the above yields `0` and `2`, respectively.

---

**A *string*-based solution**:

To offer a more concise (also culture-invariant) alternative to [Bender The Greatest's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58615318/45375):

```
$a = 0.0001
("$a" -replace '.+\.').Length # -> 4, the number of decimal places
```

**Caveat**: This solution relies on the *default string representation* of a `[double]` number, which need not match the original input format; for instance, `.0100`, when stringified later, becomes `'0.01'`; however, as discussed above, you can preserve trailing zeros if you start with a `[decimal]` literal: `.0100d` stringifies to `'0.0100'` (input number of decimals preserved).

- `"$a"`, uses an *expandable string* (PowerShell's string interpolation) to create a *culture-invariant* string representation of the number so as to ensure that the string representation uses `.` as the decimal mark.

  - In effect, PowerShell calls `$a.ToString([cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)` behind the scenes.<sup>[1]</sup>.
  - By contrast, `.ToString()` (argument-less) applies the rules of the *current* culture, and in some cultures it is `,` - not `.` - that is used as the decimal mark.
  - *Caveat*: If you use just `$a` as the LHS of `-replace`, `$a` is *implicitly* stringified, in which case you - curiously - get culture-*sensitive* behavior, as with `.ToString()` - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10948).
- `-replace '.+\.'` effectively removes all characters up to and including the decimal point from the input string, and `.Length` counts the characters in the resulting string - the number of decimal places.

---

<sup>[1] Note that *casts* from strings in PowerShell too use the invariant culture (effectively, `::Parse($value, [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)` is called) so that in order to parse a a *culture-local* string representation you'll need to use the `::Parse()` method explicitly; e.g.,  `[double]::Parse('1,2')`, not `[double] '1,2'`.</sup>