# Is there a fast and non-fancy C# code/algorithm to compress a string of comma separated digits close to maximum info density?

Tags: c#, algorithm, compression, adhoc

In a nutshell, I programmed myself into a corner by creating a CLR aggregate that performs row id concatenation, so I say:

```
select SumKeys(id), name from SomeTable where name='multiple rows named this'
```

and I get something like:

```
SumKeys         name
--------        ---------
1,4,495         multiple rows named this
```

But it dies when SumKeys gets > 8000 chars and I don't think I can do anything about it.

As a quick fix (it's only failing 1% of the time for my application) I thought I might compress the string down and I thought some of you bright people out there might know a slick way to do this.

Something like base64 made for 0-9 and a comma?

Comment: related: [Compressing big number (or string) to small value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355100/compressing-big-number-or-string-to-small-value)

Answer (score 2):

You'd be much better of if you figure out more reasonable storage for your data (maybe HashSet)...

But for compression try regular System.IO.Compression.GZipStream ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx ) and convert resulting byte array to base64 string if needed... or store as byte array.

Answer (score 2):

How about a hexadecimal representation, where every digit represents a 4-bit half of a character byte (a nibble), with `0xa` used as the comma? You will only get a 50% compression, but it is fast and simple.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how "fancy" you'd consider it, but zip/gzip compression is highly effective for any text (sometimes to the tune of 90% reduction or better).  Since you're already working with C# and CLR integration, it hopefully wouldn't be too hard to setup/deploy.  I haven't tinkered with any C# libraries for compression yet, but it's easy to find them.  For example: http://sharpdevelop.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/ or http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/ or even http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx

Or an easier option might be to switch your field to text or varchar/nvarchar(max), if that's feasible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Huffman tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding). This is basically an algorithm to compress ascii into binary. I was told that it is basically what WinZIP uses, but I'm not sure if that is really true or not. I did a quick search for `huffman coding c#` and there seems to be at least one decent implementation out there, though I haven't used any of them.

If your "vocabulary" is just digits and commas, a Hoffman tree will get you very good compression.

http://www.enusbaum.com/blog/2009/05/22/example-huffman-compression-routine-in-c/

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM SomeTable GROUP BY name WHERE name = 'multiple rows named this'
```

Comment: too bad sql server doesn't have that :)

Comment: :S I thought you were on MySQL for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a method that will work with SQL Server:

```
SELECT
  STUFF((
    SELECT ','+id FROM SomeTable a WHERE a.name = b.name FOR XML PATH('')
  ),1,1,'') AS SumKeys, name
FROM SomeTable b
GROUP BY name
WHERE name = 'multiple rows named this'
```

The WHERE clause is optional