# What's an Efficient Inversion of the Convert-to-Arbitrary-Base C# Function?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I need to convert an integer into a base64-character representation. I'm using OxA3's answer on this thread: [Quickest way to convert a base 10 number to any base in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923771/quickest-way-to-convert-a-base-10-number-to-any-base-in-net)

How do I inverse this to get my original integer back, given a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Joel Mueller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579970/whats-an-efficient-inversion-of-the-convert-to-arbitrary-base-c-function/3580116#3580116) should guide you the base-64 case.

In response to the preliminary code you've provided in [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579970/whats-an-efficient-inversion-of-the-convert-to-arbitrary-base-c-function/3579977#3579977), you can definitely improve its efficiency by changing the code to accomplish what your `for` loop is doing (effectively an O(N) `IndexOf`) to use a hash lookup (which should make it O(1)).

I am basing this on the assumption that `baseChars` is a field that you initialize in your class's constructor. If this is correct, make the following adjustment:

```
private Dictionary<char, int> baseChars;

// I don't know what your class is called.
public MultipleBaseNumberFormatter(IEnumerable<char> baseCharacters)
{
    // check for baseCharacters != null and Count > 0

    baseChars = baseCharacters
        .Select((c, i) => new { Value = c, Index = i })
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Value, x => x.Index);
}
```

Then in your `StringToInt` method:

```
char next = encodedString[currentChar];

// No enumerating -- we've gone from O(N) to O(1)!
if (!characterIndices.TryGetValue(next, out nextCharIndex))
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Input includes illegal characters.");
}
```

Comment: Using a dictionary is a great idea.

Answer (score 3):

I have a first-pass of a working version here, albeit I'm not sure how efficient it is.

```
public static int StringToInt(string encodedString, char[] baseChars)
    {
        int result = 0;
        int sourceBase = baseChars.Length;
        int nextCharIndex = 0;

        for (int currentChar = encodedString.Length - 1; currentChar >= 0; currentChar--)
        {
            char next = encodedString[currentChar];

            // For loop gets us: baseChar.IndexOf(char) => int
            for (nextCharIndex = 0; nextCharIndex < baseChars.Length; nextCharIndex++)
            {
                if (baseChars[nextCharIndex] == next)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            // For character N (from the end of the string), we multiply our value
            // by 64^N. eg. if we have "CE" in hex, F = 16 * 13.
            result += (int)Math.Pow(baseChars.Length, encodedString.Length - 1 - currentChar) * nextCharIndex;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: what is baseChars for, can I replace it with an input of the base I'm interested in converting to?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version using Linq functionality and .NET Framework 4.0 Zip extension to perform the calculation.

```
public static int StringToInt(string encodedString, char[] baseChars) {
    int sourceBase = baseChars.Length;

    var dict = baseChars
        .Select((c, i) => new { Value = c, Index = i })
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Value, x => x.Index);

    return encodedString.ToCharArray()
        // Get a list of positional weights in descending order, calcuate value of weighted position
        .Zip(Enumerable.Range(0,encodedString.Length).Reverse(), (f,s) => dict[f] * (int)Math.Pow(sourceBase,s)) 
        .Sum();
}
```

FYI, calculating the dictionary once outside the function would be more efficient for a large batch of transformations.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete solution that converts a base10 number to baseK and back:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int i = 100;

        Console.WriteLine("Int:               " + i);

        // Default base definition. By moving chars around in this string, we can further prevent
        // users from guessing identifiers.
        var baseDefinition = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        //var baseDefinition = "WBUR17GHO8FLZIA059M4TESD2VCNQKXPJ63Y"; // scrambled to minimize guessability

        // Convert base10 to baseK
        var newId = ConvertToBaseK(i, baseDefinition);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("To base{0} (short): {1}", baseDefinition.Length, newId));

        // Convert baseK to base10
        var convertedInt2 = ConvertToBase10(newId, baseDefinition);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Converted back:    {0}", convertedInt2));
    }

    public static string ConvertToBaseK(int val, string baseDef)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        int targetBase = baseDef.Length;

        do
        {
            result = baseDef[val % targetBase] + result;
            val = val / targetBase;
        } 
        while (val > 0);

        return result;
    }

    public static int ConvertToBase10(string str, string baseDef)
    {
        double result = 0;
        for (int idx = 0; idx < str.Length; idx++)
        {
            var idxOfChar = baseDef.IndexOf(str[idx]);
            result += idxOfChar * System.Math.Pow(baseDef.Length, (str.Length-1) - idx);
        }

        return (int)result;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ashes999 fair enough.. link removed and answer replaced with code.

Comment: Great solution, any idea if this conversion is efficient?.

Answer (score 0):

If base-64 is really what you need rather than "any base" then everything you need is already built in to the framework:

```
int orig = 1337;
byte[] origBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(orig);
string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(origBytes);
byte[] decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(encoded);
int converted = BitConverter.ToInt32(decoded, 0);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(orig == converted);
```

Comment: god thats ugly compared to C. Don't know why people rave so much about this C#.

Comment: @ldog: Haha, I can't imagine that anybody who's ever raved about C# has picked *converting strings to integers for arbitrary bases* as a scenario in which it really shines. Comparing C# to C in general seems rather pointless to me, in fact. Suppose I complained about how hard it is to rapidly develop a rich GUI application in C and asked why anybody likes it.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's working. The original function maps (1, 2, 3, 4) to (b, c, d, e); this one maps them to (AqAAAA, AgAAAA, AwAAAA, BAAAAA). Not the original intention, which is to use less characters for numbers.

Comment: You said you wanted base-64. That's standard base-64 encoding on the 4 bytes that make up an integer (that is, 1 = [0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0]). Unfortunately, `Convert.ToBase64String` only accepts byte arrays.

Comment: The original Stack Overflow post lays it out as converting to "any base int." That's what I'm after. Cheers though.