# How do you convert a string into octal in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, octal

Is it possible to convert a string of text from a textbox into octal numbers? If so, how do I convert octal to text and text to octal?

Oh, now I understand how it works. I thought that hex and octal were two different things, but really it's two different bases. Sorry for the second post.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Octal numbers"? Please explain expected inputs and outputs.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504034/how-do-you-convert-a-string-into-hexadecimal-in-vb-net/10504215#10504215

Comment: Agreed base are different. But if you understand how to convert to hexa, converting to octa is trivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Convert.ToInt32(String, Int32) Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614.aspx) and pass 8 as base.

```
Dim octal As Int32 = Convert.ToInt32(TxtOctalNumber.Text, 8)
```

The second parameter `fromBase`

```
Type: System.Int32
The base of the number in value, which must be 2, 8, 10, or 16.
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert into octal, use [Convert.ToInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (val, 8). Convert.ToInt32 supports limited bases, 2, 8, 10, and 16.

To convert into any base,

```
Public Shared Function IntToString(value As Integer, baseChars As Char()) As String
    Dim result As String = String.Empty
    Dim targetBase As Integer = baseChars.Length

    Do
        result = baseChars(value Mod targetBase) + result
        value = value / targetBase
    Loop While value > 0

    Return result
End Function
```

The above function comes from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923771/quickest-way-to-convert-a-base-10-number-to-any-base-in-net). C#-to-VB conversion was done using [this](http://converter.telerik.com/). (I have pasted my response from [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504034/how-do-you-convert-a-string-into-hexadecimal-in-vb-net/10504215#10504215).)

Comment: but arent hex and octal different? I used a converter and had different results

Comment: They are different - octal is base 8 and hex is base 16

Comment: Agreed base are different. But if you understand how to convert to hexa, converting to octa is trivial.