# Make a <li> invisible in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

is there any way to make the li with the id liTest and liLogout invisible?

I tried this:

```
liTest.Visible = false
```

but I get this error:

> Error 3,  The name 'litest' does not exist in the current context

```
 <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
     <AnonymousTemplate>
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
             <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
             <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
             <li><a  ID="liTest" runat="server" >test</a></li>
             <li><a ID="liLogout" runat="server"  >Logout</a></li>
         </ul>
     </AnonymousTemplate>
```

Comment: maybe use id instead of ID

Comment: @dotctor I believe that shouldn't have any effect here, it should still fail that way, but if you do believe it should work, please post it as an answer rather than as a comment.

Comment: Tried id instead of ID, still not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference: [How to: Access Server Controls by ID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y81z8326%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

> When a control is not inside a naming container, you can get a
>   reference to it by using the control's ID. When a control is inside a
>   naming container, you must call a method that searches the naming
>   container for the control's ID. A control might also be inside a
>   naming container that you do not have direct access to.

So, you need to write a function to search for the design time ID at **runtime**, like so:

```
private Control FindControlRecursive(Control rootControl, string controlID)
{
    if (rootControl.ID == controlID) return rootControl;

    foreach (Control controlToSearch in rootControl.Controls)
    {
        Control controlToReturn = 
            FindControlRecursive(controlToSearch, controlID);
        if (controlToReturn != null) return controlToReturn;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then call this function to get a reference to the control you need:

```
var ctrl = FindControlRecursive(this, "liTest");
if (ctrl !=null) {
   ctrl.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
<li><a  ID="liTest" runat="server" >test</a></li>
<li><a ID="liLogout" runat="server"  >Logout</a></li>
```

With this:

```
<li ID="liTest" runat="server"><a>test</a></li>
<li ID="liLogout" runat="server"><a>Logout</a></li>
```

This makes the LI controls accessible by server software.

If you also want to have the a controls accessible by server software, than you could use something like this:

```
<li ID="liTest" runat="server"><a ID="liTestA" runat="server">test</a></li>
<li ID="liLogout" runat="server"><a ID="liLogoutA" runat="server">Logout</a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks to Cliodhna I have a bronze badge! This is my first and only reward yet. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504034/how-do-you-convert-a-string-into-hexadecimal-in-vb-net for my latest answer (comment actually).

Answer (score -3):

Can you use CSS?

```
#liTest, #liLogout {display:none;}
```

EDIT:
Your id is not for **li** element, it's for **a**.

Comment: I can use CSS, but i would like to make the li invisible for example if( i == 1), I tried  to do it like this : <li ID="liLogout" runat="server">Logout</li> but that aint working either