# How to convert Decimal To Hex using VB?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I tried this code to convert Decimal to hex, but it doesn't work.

```
Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As String = sASC
    i = Convert.ToInt32(x, 16)
    TextBox8.Text = i
```

This is what i want to conver.
912,697,583,1065,261,627,53,703,544,697,924,1003,697

Comment: Is this a string containing digits separated by a comma?

Comment: yes, it is. i want to convert it as decimal to hex.

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504034/how-do-you-convert-a-string-into-hexadecimal-in-vb-net

Comment: For a start, you have four-digit number groups. Do you mean you want to convert each group into hex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach your goal with a single line of code in Linq

```
Dim input = "912,697,583,1065,261,627,53,703,544,697,924,1003,697"

Dim result = String.Join(",", input.Split(","c).
                              Select(Function(x) _
                              Convert.ToInt32(x).ToString("X")))
Console.WriteLine(result)

' 390,2B9,247,429,105,273,35,2BF,220,2B9,39C,3EB,2B9
```

This will convert each value in the input string in its equivalent hex value and rebuild the string with the comma separator

Back to base 10 values is  (result is from the previous code)

```
Dim result2 = String.Join(",", result.Split(","c).
                          Select(Function(x) _
                          Convert.ToInt32(x, 16).ToString()))
Console.WriteLine(result2)
```

Comment: Thanks, now how to convert from Hex To Decimal? To reach same format Above.

Comment: _Convert.ToInt32(value, frombase)_ Meaning that you apply the same logic to the hexdecimal string but apply the Convert.ToInt32 overload that specify a second parameter equals to 16

Comment: I understand @Steve, but i don't know how to do that in code, could you give me code. plz

Comment: Thanks, but is this code work if does not have a comma?? What should i do for that?

Comment: No this code works splitting the individual numbers at the comma, Without a comma what would be the rule to divide the string?

Comment: I don't know, can we replace "comma" and put another "char" or Zero "0"?

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand these changes. Perhaps you could post a new question explaining in detail what are your changed requirements. In this way more people will see your problem and could help better than just me in this now 'old' question.