# Displaying a decimal number into its equivalent Binary number

Tags: c#

I tried the following code for displaying a number's binary equivalent but i am getting an error and i am not getting the reason behind the error:

```
using System;

class NumToBin{
     static void main(){
        int num=7;
        for(int i=0;i<=32;i++){
            if(num &(1<<i)==1)// getting an error on this line
                Console.WriteLine("1");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("0");
        }
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

I got the following error for the above code and i dont know the reason behind this error?

`Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool' (CS0019)`

Comment: Have you tried `Convert.ToString(i, 2)` ?

Comment: Also, for reference (even though this really isn't what your question is about):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923771/quickest-way-to-convert-a-base-10-number-to-any-base-in-net

Comment: @L.B: Your comment deserves to be a full-fledged answer. Anytime you can reduce code by 90% or so is a beautiful thing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operator precedence error, try `if ((num & (1<<i)) == 1)`

There are **only** 32 bits in an `int`.  Change for loop predicate to `i < 32`, instead of `i<=32`.

or:

```
for(int i=0; i < 32; i++)
    Console.WriteLine((num & (1<<i)) == 0 ? "0" : "1");
```

**UPDATED**

```
for(int i=31; 0 <= i; --i)
    Console.WriteLine(((num >> i) & 1) == 0 ? "0" : "1");
```

Comment: With your logic i am getting 11100000000000000000000000000000 for 7. Can i anyhow reverse it to get 00000000000000000000000000000111 which is more meaningful for binary numbers?

Comment: @Raptor - Reverse your for loop. Count from 32 down to 0.

Comment: @Richard Schneider- The updated code is still giving the same output.

Comment: @Raptor, sorry its getting late in bangkok and my mind is lazy!

Comment: @RichardSchneider, Sorry to bother you again, but now its going in an infinite loop. You wrote i++ instead of i--

Answer (score 5):

Error is a result of [operator order of precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), to fix it you simply need to add parentheses, change:

```
if(num &(1<<i)==1)
```

to

```
if((num & (1<<i)) == 1)
```