# How to convert part of a char array to a string

Tags: c#

I want to convert part of a char array to a string.  What is the best way to do that.

I know I can do the following for the whole array

```
char[] chars = {'a', ' ', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g'};
string s = new string(chars);
```

but what about just elements 2 to 4 for example?

I also know I can loop through the array and extract them, but I wondered if there was a more succinct way of doing it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use the [`String` constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131424.aspx) which takes a char array, an index and a length:

```
String text = new String(chars, 2, 3); // Index 2-4 inclusive
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use LINQ

```
char[] chars = { 'a', ' ', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g' };
string str = new string(chars.Skip(2).Take(2).ToArray());
```

But off course [string overloaded constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131424.aspx) is the way to go