# Is there any function in the C language which can convert base of decimal number?

Tags: c

I want to know if there is any function in the C language which can convert base of decimal number binary or Decimal to Hexadecimal or etc.

Comment: You told us C but tagged the question asp.net? Do you mean C#?

Comment: Also what is a dacible?? and what do you mean by ***binary or D to X or etc.***?

Comment: What do you mean base? Decimals are all base 10? Do you want to round it?

Comment: @RononDex I took a guess he meant decimal...

Comment: @Liath If that is so, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923771/quickest-way-to-convert-a-base-10-number-to-any-base-in-net

Comment: However your real question is, for sure simple google query will answer you.

Comment: If you really mean C despite the asp.net tag, perhaps you're looking for the itoa or ltoa functions.  These are not part of ANSI-C but are supported by some compilers.  Google can tell you more.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this..

```
int convert(int number,int base){
    if(number == 0 || base==10)
        return number;
    return (number % base) + 10*convert(number / base, base);
}

int main () {
   int a;
   scanf("%d",&a);
   //Lets convert 123 in decimal to octal
   printf("%d\n",convert(123, 8));
   return 0;
}
```

Let me know if  this helps.. :)

Comment: i m not able to implement this code pls send completely code. thank you

Comment: As i have Studies this code, this can convert only Decimal number to Octal, this can not convert Decimal Number into another Base.

Comment: @user3197468: The main() function is just an example. Change the 8 into whatever base you want.

Comment: If you want to convert decimal to binary call the function like convert(123, 2).

Comment: this function is not right working, i have run this function.

Comment: @user3197468 >> Try to understand the logic except searching for code.. I am sure that the time you spent searching for code, if you tried to understand the logic you could write it yourself. We are here to help not to supply only the code and make others lazy.. :)

Comment: Thanks sir, But I got the answer of this question there is one particular function which can convert the base of an given number. the function is itoa(number,array,base)

Comment: As far as I can remember this function has some compilation issue.. Hope you can overcome this. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard libraries or functions to do that

You can always write a small function to do your calculations.. It won't be hard to find codes (If you don't wanna write) but I suggest to write them your self with your basic knowledge on number conversions..

Comment: Dear Friends I got the answer of this question there is one particular function which can convert the base of an given number. the function is                                                        itoa(number,array,base)

Comment: Yes, that's an easy way :) but there could be limitation on compiling supprt, that's why I suggested.. anyway solved the problem