# Logic to generate an alphabetical sequence in C#

Tags: c#, sequences, alphabetical, sequencing, sequence-generators

The sequence should go like this.
**A-Z,AA-AZ,BA-BZ,CA-CZ,.......,ZA-ZZ**
After **ZZ** it should start from **AAA**.
Then **AAA** to **ZZZ** and then **AAAA** to **ZZZZ** and so on.

This sequence is pretty much like that of an Excel sheet.

**Edit: Added my code**

```
        private void SequenceGenerator()
    {
        var numAlpha = new Regex("(?<Numeric>[0-9]*)(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]*)");
        var match = numAlpha.Match(txtBNo.Text);

        var alpha = match.Groups["Alpha"].Value;
        var num = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups["Numeric"].Value);
        lastChar = alpha.Substring(alpha.Length - 1);

        if (lastChar=="Z")
        {
            lastChar = "A";
            txtBNo.Text = num.ToString() + "A" + alpha.Substring(0, alpha.Length - 1) + lastChar;
        }

        else
        {
            txtBNo.Text = num.ToString() + alpha.Substring(0, alpha.Length - 1) + Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToChar(lastChar)) + 1);
        }
    }
```

This is what I've done. But, I know that is a wrong logic.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to work on this at all?

Comment: How about you give it a shot and come back if you run into a more specific problem?

Comment: You convert the numbers 0...x to base-26 (with the symbols A-Z). Solved :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quickest way to convert a base 10 number to any base in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923771/quickest-way-to-convert-a-base-10-number-to-any-base-in-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucky for you, I've done this once before. the problems I've encountered is that in the Excel sheet there is no 0, not even in double 'digit' 'numbers'. meaning you start with a (that's 1) and then from z (that's 26) you go straight to aa (27). This is why is't **not a simple base conversion problem**, and you need some extra code to handle this.
Testing the function suggested by xanatos results with the following:

NumToLetters(0) --> A

NumToLetters(25) --> Z

NumToLetters(26) --> BA

My solution has more code but it has been tested against Excel and is fully compatible, except it starts with 0 and not 1, meaning that a is 0, z is 25, aa is 26, zz 701, aaa is 702 and so on). you can change it to start from 1 if you want, it's fairly easy.

```
private static string mColumnLetters = "zabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

// Convert Column name to 0 based index
public static int ColumnIndexByName(string ColumnName)
    {
        string CurrentLetter;
        int ColumnIndex, LetterValue, ColumnNameLength;
        ColumnIndex = -1; // A is the first column, but for calculation it's number is 1 and not 0. however, Index is alsways zero-based.
        ColumnNameLength = ColumnName.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < ColumnNameLength; i++)
        {
            CurrentLetter = ColumnName.Substring(i, 1).ToLower();
            LetterValue = mColumnLetters.IndexOf(CurrentLetter);
            ColumnIndex += LetterValue * (int)Math.Pow(26, (ColumnNameLength - (i + 1)));
        }
        return ColumnIndex;
    }

// Convert 0 based index to Column name
public static string ColumnNameByIndex(int ColumnIndex)
    {
        int ModOf26, Subtract;
        StringBuilder NumberInLetters = new StringBuilder();
        ColumnIndex += 1; // A is the first column, but for calculation it's number is 1 and not 0. however, Index is alsways zero-based.
        while (ColumnIndex > 0)
        {
            if (ColumnIndex <= 26)
            {
                ModOf26 = ColumnIndex;
                NumberInLetters.Insert(0, mColumnLetters.Substring(ModOf26, 1));
                ColumnIndex = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                ModOf26 = ColumnIndex % 26;
                Subtract = (ModOf26 == 0) ? 26 : ModOf26;
                ColumnIndex = (ColumnIndex - Subtract) / 26;
                NumberInLetters.Insert(0, mColumnLetters.Substring(ModOf26, 1));
            }
        }
        return NumberInLetters.ToString().ToUpper();
    }
```

Comment: Your code works with slight modifications. :)

Comment: ColumnIndexByName has trouble with some values  

Index 676 ColumnName ZA back to Index 0  

Index 677 ColumnName ZB back to Index 1

Comment: @DougFerguson This code is probably 10 years old by now (I know it was posted 8 years ago). If there's a bug, you might be in a better position than me to solve it, since it's a very long time since I last used it.

Answer (score 8):

As I've wrote in the comment, it's a base-conversion problem, where your output is in *base-26*, with symbols *A-Z*

```
static string NumToLetters(int num)
{
    string str = string.Empty;

    // We need to do at least a "round" of division
    // to handle num == 0
    do
    {
        // We have to "prepend" the new digit
        str = (char)('A' + (num % 26)) + str;
        num /= 26;
    }
    while (num != 0);

    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this method:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GenerateItems()
{
    var buffer = new[] { '@' };
    var maxIdx = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        var i = maxIdx;
        while (true)
        {
            if (buffer[i] < 'Z')
            {
                buffer[i]++;
                break;
            }

            if (i == 0)
            {
                buffer = Enumerable.Range(0, ++maxIdx + 1).Select(c => 'A').ToArray();
                break;
            }

            buffer[i] = 'A';
            i--;
        }

        yield return new string(buffer);
    }
    // ReSharper disable once FunctionNeverReturns
}
```

This is **infinite generator** of alphabetical sequence you need, **you must restrict count of items** like this:

```
var sequence = GenerateItems().Take(10000).ToArray();
```

**Do not call it like this (it cause infinite loop):**

```
foreach (var i in GenerateItems())
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but you need to only use the value of the last cell.

Comment: "but you need to only use the value of the last cell"  - I think I don't understand you, can you explain?

Comment: try running your solution. you will get an array of string containing all the values between A to the desired value. so if you run it like this var sequence = GenerateItems().Take(4).ToArray(); you will get an array like this: {"A", "B", "C", "D"}.

Comment: Yes, of course, it is required in question, isn't it? I can add some skip logic to implement startFrom functionality.

Comment: Maybe you are correct and I've missed it. I've suggested a way to translate a single number to it's string representation and back, but perhaps I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Yes, it is, but I will implement startFrom logic anyway - it would be more usable solution :-)