# How to convert a number to base 24 and convert it back?

Tags: c#, radix

How can I convert a number to a base-24 string? And how can I convert this string back to a number?

e.g.: 25 in base-10 is 11 in base-24, 2B in base-24 is 48+11 = 59 in base-10

Comment: Other than the fact that you don't seem to be able to do hex conversion manually, `decimal` is a floating point type, so a decimal can be `5.2`... a floating point hex is something I haven't ever seen (not that it isn't possible, but...)

Comment: @xanatos sorry, I use google translator for 'Decimal' and '24Hex' cause i don't know how to say "every 10 in 1" and "every 24 in 1" in English.

Comment: @ASh, that post only seems to cover going one way (base 10 -> base x)

Comment: @OhMyDog Ok... I've changed your question to be clearer.

Comment: @DavidArno, backward is simpler and also one answer has additional link where backward conversion is implemented: http://www.pvladov.com/2012/05/decimal-to-arbitrary-numeral-system.html, http://www.pvladov.com/2012/07/arbitrary-to-decimal-numeral-system.html

Comment: @xanatos thank you & i'm gonna to give google translator a -1... -_-!

Comment: *`From`* and *`To`* methods: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923771/quickest-way-to-convert-a-base-10-number-to-any-base-in-net/35004409#35004409

Answer (score 1):

This code is working fine both decimal to hex and hex to decimal

```
        var HexVal = "2B";
        int DecimalVal = Convert.ToInt32(HexVal, 16);
        Console.WriteLine(DecimalVal);
        string HexVal1 = DecimalVal.ToString("X");
        Console.WriteLine(HexVal1);
```