# Base to base conversion

Tags: c#, radix

I'm trying to find some function that converts from any base to any other base.

In `Java`, I used `BigInteger` which allowed me to receive a number in a pre-defined base like this: `.nextBigInteger(radix)` and then convert it to any other base by `.ToString(radix)`.

I'm trying to do the same in `C#`, but problem is `BigInteger` isn't designed to get the number's radix. Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/923814/3711660

Comment: I already saw that and it's used to convert base 10 to other bases. I need any base to any base.

Comment: @OmerAviv Clearly you can do it in two steps... BaseN to Base10 and then Base10 to BaseM

Comment: Take this instead any to any http://stackoverflow.com/a/924827/3711660

Comment: @Toumash That's for `int`, not `BigInteger`.

Comment: @OmerAviv do you need `BigInteger`? Or `int` will suffice? From your text i thought you were using `BigInteger` only for the conversion purpose