# C# base converter

Tags: c#, radix, base-conversion

I stumbled on this method which should do a base convert from a 10 base to *radix* base, so for example if I pass *28, 16* it should return 1c which is the hexadecimal representation of the decimal 28

```
private static string convertTo(long value, int radix)
{
    char[] alphabet = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv".ToCharArray();
    string result = "";

    if (value < radix) {
        return alphabet[value].ToString();
    }

    long index;
    while (value != 0)
    {
        index = value % radix;
        value = Convert.ToInt64(Math.Floor(value / radix));  
        result += alphabet[index].ToString();
    }
    return result;
}
```

<strike>I'm rewriting that part of the program in PHP.</strike> By reading the code above, and predicting output manually, it returns c1 where it should return 1c for *28, 16*

My finding is that this method returns a reversed representation of string in a given base, *c1* instead of correctly *1c*

Because I do not have a C# compiler I could not verify my findings.

So here are my two questions:

1. Are my calculations right that the above method calld with *28, 16* returns *c1*?
2. I suppose symbols (digits/alphabets), in any base, are written so that base exponents decreases by 1 **as we go from left to write**, so for example in *decimal* representation *312* means 300 `(3 * 10 ^ 2)` + 10 `(1 * 10 ^ 1)` + 2 `(2 * 10 ^ 0)`.. is that *absolutely* *always* correct?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider correct, and that is a flipped c1 (which I believe is the return of that method above). If that's all correct I would end up using strrev( base_convert( 28, 10, 16 ) ) to achieve that effect. but I'm not sure of my findings and that's the question :)

Comment: There are multiple free C# compilers available including Visual Studio Community. What's stopping you from testing it?

Comment: @Jeff I do not have Windows and I cannot use VS. And without VS I will have to wrap this function in a class to test it, but I do not have that skill with C#.

Comment: You can compile and test C# code here: http://csharppad.com/

Comment: You can also use mono under Linux.

Comment: Side note: if you happen to hit this question by searching for base/radix conversion - correct answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923771/quickest-way-to-convert-a-base-10-number-to-any-base-in-net

Comment: I was also thinking if MS is doing something differently, in a reversed model, who knows what else... and which is more wise? asking an expert or testing a code for a language I never used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For me, yes. the snippet in C# (as it is) should return C1, instead of 1C. You will need to reverse the string *result* before returning it. (or use instead something like `result = string.Concat(alphabet[index].toString());` when creating the *result* string)
2. That's correct. It also works in all the other bases, i.e. if we take your example (28), you'll have :

28 = 2 * 10^1 + 8 * 10^0 (base 10)

28 = **1** * 16^1 + **12** * 16^0 (base 16) = **1C**

28 = **3** * 8^1 + **2** * 8^0 (base 8) = **32**

etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that code needs to reverse the output.  Below are the results when I ran that code in Visual Studio 2015, and the corresponding output in the Locals window.

```
    var ret1 = convertTo(28, 16);
    var ret2 = convertTo(28, 10);
    var ret3 = convertTo(10, 10);

    ret1    "c1"    string
    ret2    "82"    string
    ret3    "01"    string
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct `convertTo(28, 16) == c1`
The loop in the code should be:

```
while (value != 0)
{
    index = value / radix; // implicit integer division  
    value = value % radix;
    result += alphabet[index].ToString();
}
```

As to your second question I believe that to be correct also - that's more for a mathematics expert to verify though.

Comment: Since `value / radix` is already a `long` because C# defines overloads of `operator /` that do integer division, you should get rid of `Convert.ToInt64(Math.Floor(`.

Comment: Thanks @JeppeStigNielsen that slipped by me.

Comment: You must remove the `Math.Floor` part as well!