# Get next string following array of char

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string

I have an `Array` of `chars`, which is completely random except that every character occurs at most once.

I also have a string containing only characters that are present in the array. I want this string to be "counted upwards" (if that makes sense), like `"111"` becomes `"112"`, or `"aaa"` becomes `"aab"`.

Let´s say the `Array` of `chars` contains `1, 2, and 3`. The example above works, but when the string is `"333"` (should become `"1111"`), my function returns an empty - or wrong - `string`.

If I call the function again, providing the wrong `string`, after a few times it returns the correct value (`"1111"`).

Why does this happen?

This is my function:

```
Public Function getNextString(ByVal currentStr As String, ByVal pattern() As Char) As String 
    'currentStr is the string which I want to count upwards, pattern() is the array of chars

    Dim nextStr As String = ""

    Dim currentStrArray() As Char = currentStr.ToCharArray
    Dim currenStrPosition As Integer = currentStrArray.Length - 1

    Dim finished As Boolean = False
    Do Until finished = True
        Dim newPosition As Integer = getPositionInArray(currentStrArray(currentStrPosition)) 'this is a custom function, should be self-explaining
        If newPosition = Nothing Then Return Nothing
        newPosition += 1

        Try
            currentStrArray(currenStrPosition) = pattern(newPosition)
            finished = True
        Catch ex As IndexOutOfRangeException
            currentStrArray(currentStrPosition) = pattern(0)
            currentStrPosition -= 1
        End Try

        If currentStrPosition < 0 Then
            nextStr = pattern(0)
            finished = True
        End If
    Loop

    For i As Integer = 0 To currentStrArray.Length - 1
        nextStr = nextStr & currentStrArray(i)
    Next

    Return nextStr
End Function
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

As an example, I have the array `{"1","2","3"}`. My `string` is first `"111"`. I want to test these `strings` hashsums. After testing that string, I need the next `string`, `"112"`. Then, `"113"`, `"121"`, `"122"`, and so on. When the string reaches `"333"` and the string is not the one I'm looking for, it was obviously no string with only 3 characters (all 3-character-combinations possible with the array have been tried). So I need to start again using 4 characters. That´s why `"333"` is supposed to become `"1111"`. 
Hope this helps.

EDIT #2:

I found the error. I redimensioned my array incorrectly, so the last index was empty. This made my `strings` look weird. Thank you all for your working solutions, have a good day!

Comment: Why should 333 become 1111?

Comment: I want to count upwards using only the characters in the array. if it contains only 1, 2, and 3, it should only use these. Like if you have all 10 digits, 99 becomes 100.

Comment: Still not clear. You should show your sample array and string. Even if it is `{"1","2","3"}` i dont understand why `333` becomes `1111`. Why is 333+1=1111?

Comment: I think that it's basically substituting the numbers with random chars, so if the array is `{"a", "b", "c"}` you should treat "a" as 0, "b" as 1, "c" as 3, and count in a base 3.

Comment: @Zohar Peled These characters can be any Ascii characters, and the array size can depend from only 1 char to 256... how would i do that

Comment: @Ian Still don´t get why that requirement is that funny... it seems to be quite logical to me! I like your answer though, I´d upvote it if I had the required reputation.

Comment: @Ian no offense taken :) It´s just like it´s not calculation, but more like brute forcing. Trying all combinations possible, which has nothing to do with maths in my eyes! btw, is there anything I need to accept or something after my question was edited?

Comment: I see! thanks for introducing me to the basics of this site :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I think you're spot on with `"333" + 1 <> "1111"`. Take a look at my answer - I've shown that `"333" + 1 = "2111"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I would convert to a number, add 1 and then convert back to a string.

Convert the string to a number:

```
Function ConvertStringToNumber(input As String, pattern As Char()) As Integer
    Dim number As Integer = 0
    Dim charDigits = pattern.ToList()
    Dim numberBase = charDigits.Count
    For i As var = 0 To input.Length - 1
        Dim digit = charDigits.IndexOf(input(input.Length - 1 - i))
        If digit <> -1 Then
            number += digit * CInt(Math.Pow(numberBase, i))
        End If
    Next
    Return number
End Function
```

Convert the number back to a string:

```
Function convertNumberToString(number As Integer, pattern As Char()) As String
    Dim charDigits = pattern.ToList()
    Dim numberBase = charDigits.Count
    Dim buffer = New Stack(Of Char)()
    'var j = buffer.Length;
    While number > 0
        buffer.Push(charDigits(number Mod numberBase))
        number = number / numberBase
    End While
    Dim sb = New StringBuilder()
    While buffer.Count > 0
        sb.Append(buffer.Pop())
    End While

    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

Now that you have conversion functions, all you have to do is something like this:

```
Function getNextString(ByVal currentStr As String, ByVal pattern() As Char) As String
    Dim number = ConvertStringToNumber(currentStr, pattern)
    number += 1
    Return convertNumberToString(number, pattern)
End Function
```

Comment: btw, "333" should be converted to "2111" in the example you wrote in your question, since "1111" is basically 0000.

Comment: Accepted as it´s easy and working and also in vb. See edit #2 in the question

Comment: I wrote my answer in c# and converted to vb.net using an online tool. I suspect that the conversion was less then perfect since [the c# version works as I intended.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7MJ1MV)

Comment: You´re right. Of course it is working. but when I tested with my application, it didn´t, as I made a mistake elsewhere. I removed my comment.

Comment: BTW, this code doesn't compile with `Option Strict On`.

Comment: @Enigmativity Well, it's been a long time since I last wrote vb.net. Moved to c# and didn't look back a few years ago, so if I've made some mistakes in my answer I hope that the StackOverflow community can forgive me for that.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - LOL, I hope you didn't take offense! You would only need to change `number = number / numberBase` to `number = number \ numberBase` to avoid an invalid cast from `Double` to `Integer`.

Comment: @Enigmativity none taken :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to increment in a specific base (length of your array). What you need is a mapping function that maps your array chars to their respective numbers, then convert from your base to decimal, increment, convert back and remap.

Can you check if this link helps? [Quickest way to convert a base 10 number to any base in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923771/quickest-way-to-convert-a-base-10-number-to-any-base-in-net)

I just wrote the following in c#, it seems to work.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[] definition = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '9', 'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3'};
        string helperstring = new String(definition);
        int basenumber = definition.Length;
        string mynumberasstring = "333";
        Console.WriteLine(mynumberasstring);
        int correspondingdecimal = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mynumberasstring.Length; i++)
        {
            char x = mynumberasstring[mynumberasstring.Length - i - 1];
            int index = helperstring.IndexOf(x);
            int magnitude = 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                magnitude *= basenumber;
            Console.WriteLine(x + " -> " + index);
            correspondingdecimal += magnitude * index;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(correspondingdecimal + " -> " + ++correspondingdecimal);

        List<int> indicesofnewnumber = new List<int>();

        int newmagnitude = basenumber;
        while(correspondingdecimal > 0)
        {
            int div = correspondingdecimal / basenumber;
            int remainder = correspondingdecimal % basenumber;

            Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1} ; {2}", correspondingdecimal, div, remainder);

            indicesofnewnumber.Add(remainder);
            correspondingdecimal = div;
        }
        string newnumberasstring = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < indicesofnewnumber.Count; i++)
            newnumberasstring += definition[indicesofnewnumber[indicesofnewnumber.Count - 1 - i]];

        Console.WriteLine(newnumberasstring);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Using my function it counts upwards using the array´s index (is that the correct term?). Like, "a" in {"a","b"} is index 0; I replace it with index 1. Maybe I´m misunderstanding you...? Not sure

Comment: I would map a -> 0; b -> 1. So "ba" would become "10", which can be converted to 2; incremented 3 becomes "11" which is mapped to "bb".

Answer (score 0):

Here's the smallest code that I can think of to convert a number into an arbitrary base with arbitrary digits:

```
Dim convert As Func(Of Integer, Char(), String) = Nothing
convert = Function (n, cs) _
    If(n \ cs.Length = 0, "", convert(n \ cs.Length, cs)) + cs(n Mod cs.Length)
```

So, to convert `4` to binary I could do `convert(4, { "0"c, "1"c })` and I would get `100`.

As a sanity check if I view the first 32 (starting from zero) binary numbers using `String.Join(", ", Enumerable.Range(0, 32).Select(Function (n) convert(n, { "0"c, "1"c })))` and I get this:

> 0, 1, 10, 11, 100, 101, 110, 111, 1000, 1001, 1010, 1011, 1100, 1101, 1110, 1111, 10000, 10001, 10010, 10011, 10100, 10101, 10110, 10111, 11000, 11001, 11010, 11011, 11100, 11101, 11110, 11111

Or the first 102 decimal numbers starting from zero with `String.Join(", ", Enumerable.Range(0, 102).Select(Function (n) convert(n, "0123456789".ToCharArray())))` I get this:

> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101

So I can now use the same kind of code to get the first 50 numbers from the digits `{ "1"c, "2"c, "3"c }` using `String.Join(", ", Enumerable.Range(0, 50).Select(Function (n) convert(n, "123".ToCharArray())))` and I get this:

> 1, 2, 3, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33, 211, 212, 213, 221, 222, 223, 231, 232, 233, 311, 312, 313, 321, 322, 323, 331, 332, 333, 2111, 2112, 2113, 2121, 2122, 2123, 2131, 2132, 2133, 2211, 2212, 2213, 2221, 2222, 2223, 2231, 2232, 2233, 2311, 2312, 2313, 2321, 2322

This is the correct "counting" using the digits `{ "1"c, "2"c, "3"c }`. So, it would be correct to say that `"333" + 1 = "2111"` in this numbering system. This is the same as saying `999 + 1 = 1000` in our decimal system - it clearly doesn't go from `999 + 1 = 0000` which is the implication that `"333" + 1 = "1111"` would mean in this "123" system. Strictly speaking I should have written `"333" + "2" = "2111"` (since `"2"` represents `1`).

If you want all combinations then you would need to pad the strings to the left with the "zero" character - in this case `1`. Then this code:

```
String.Join(", ", _
    Enumerable _
        .Range(0, 500) _
        .Select(Function (n) convert(n, "123".ToCharArray()).PadLeft(4, "1"c)) _
        .Where(Function (x) x.Length = 4))
```

...gives the following 81 numbers:

> 1111, 1112, 1113, 1121, 1122, 1123, 1131, 1132, 1133, 1211, 1212, 1213, 1221, 1222, 1223, 1231, 1232, 1233, 1311, 1312, 1313, 1321, 1322, 1323, 1331, 1332, 1333, 2111, 2112, 2113, 2121, 2122, 2123, 2131, 2132, 2133, 2211, 2212, 2213, 2221, 2222, 2223, 2231, 2232, 2233, 2311, 2312, 2313, 2321, 2322, 2323, 2331, 2332, 2333, 3111, 3112, 3113, 3121, 3122, 3123, 3131, 3132, 3133, 3211, 3212, 3213, 3221, 3222, 3223, 3231, 3232, 3233, 3311, 3312, 3313, 3321, 3322, 3323, 3331, 3332, 3333

...and 81 is the total number of combinations as `3 x 3 x 3 x 3 = 81`.

---

Here are the pair of functions to convert both ways:

```
Function Convert(number As Integer, digits As Char()) As String
    Dim r = digits(number Mod digits.Length).ToString()
    If number \ digits.Length <> 0 Then
        r = Convert(number \ digits.Length, digits) + r
    End If
    Return r
End Function

Function Convert(number As String, digits As Char()) As Integer
    Dim r = Array.IndexOf(digits, number(0))
    If number.Substring(1).Length > 0 Then
        r = r * digits.Length + Convert(number.Substring(1), digits)
    End If
    Return r
End Function
```