# What is the source code of toString(16) in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am keen to know the source code for `.toString(16)` in javascript Because I would like to check logic of how the dec code converted to hex code?

Comment: That just converts it to hex. There are lot of sample code available to convert from dec to hex.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923771/quickest-way-to-convert-a-base-10-number-to-any-base-in-net

Answer (score 1):

```
Base := 16
HexNumber := ""
while(DecNumber > 0) {
    HexNumber := Concat(DecNumber % Base, HexNumber)
    DecNumber := Floor(DecNumber / Base)
}
```

Works for any base.  In hex, obviously you'll have to convert 10+ to A-F.

Edit:  Here is a version in javascript:

```
function toBaseString(base, decNumber) {
    var hexNumber = '';
    while(decNumber > 0) {
        var hexDigit = decNumber % base;
        if(hexDigit >= 10) {
            hexDigit = String.fromCharCode(hexDigit + 87);
        }
        hexNumber = hexDigit + hexNumber;
        decNumber = Math.floor(decNumber / base);
    }
    return hexNumber;
}
```

Comment: Possible to change it to JavaScript? This is not JavaScript right?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Here is a version in javascript.  There is an added portion to convert 10+ numbers to a-f in case of hex strings.  Works equally well with base 2.

Comment: Looks awesome buddy.

Comment: Hi neil please explain this line --> hexDigit = String.fromCharCode(hexDigit + 87);

Comment: In ASCII, 97 corresponds to 'a'.  Calling String.fromCharCode converts a number to its equivalent ascii character and so by taking hexDigit which is at least 10 and adding 87, I'm mapping it 1 to 1 to an ascii character.  So 10 becomes 'a', 11, becomes 'b', etc.  If I were using base 20, then I would start having characters like 'j'.  That said, numbers may not look so hot in base 9842.

Comment: Oh yes got it now.. Thankyou