# Invalid Base error when converting Java Base 27 Conversion function to C#

Tags: java, c#

I can't seem to get this to work after converting it to C#

I need it to work like the Java one but I can't seem to be able to do that what am I doing wrong?

Can anyone supply a fix and explain it please?

C#:

```
public static string Encrypt1(string strIn)
{

    string strOut = "";
    int lenIn = strIn.Length;
    int i = 0;

    while (i < lenIn)
    {
        double numRand = (int)Math.Floor(new Random().NextDouble() * 66) + 36;
        strOut += Convert.ToString((int)(strIn[i] + (char)numRand), 27) +
                Convert.ToString((int)numRand, 27);
        i++;
    }
    return strOut;
}
```

Java:

```
public String Encrypt1(String strIn) {

    String strOut = "";
    int lenIn = strIn.length();
    int i = 0;

    double numRand;

    while (i < lenIn) {
        numRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 66) + 36;
        strOut += Integer.toString((int)(strIn.charAt(i) + (char)numRand), 27) +
                Integer.toString((int)numRand, 27);
        i++;
    }
    return strOut;
}
```

The error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Invalid Base.
```

Error line:

```
   strOut += Convert.ToString((int)(strIn[i] + (char)numRand), 27) +
            Convert.ToString((int)numRand, 27);
```

Comment: `numRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 66) + 36;` says 36 in java and 33 in C#

Comment: i see changed but still not the same result ty.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve and what errors do you get?

Comment: Added the error am basically trying to encrypt a string am going to try to convert the decrypt function after this.

Comment: put debug point which line get this error

Comment: Unrelated, but you probably don't want to do `new Random()` *inside* the loop.

Comment: It appears you will need to [roll your own conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/923771/314291) to get a number in base 27. Convert.ToString only supports bases [2, 8, 10 or 16](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14kwkz77.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

This works with base 16.

```
public static string Encrypt1(string strIn)
{
    int radix = 16;

    string strOut = "";
    int lenIn = strIn.Length;
    int i = 0;

    double numRand;
    Random random = new Random();

    while (i < lenIn)
    {
        numRand = (int)Math.Floor(random.NextDouble() * 66) + 36;
        strOut += Convert.ToString((strIn[i] + (int)numRand), radix)  + 
            Convert.ToString((int)numRand, radix);
        i++;
    }
    return strOut;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, so this throws an exception.. Let me check it out.

Comment: @Puxnor, this works with base 16. See StuartLC's comment.