# all possible moves of all players

Tags: c#

in a simple game
i have 4 possible moves (up, down, left, right)
for each player

```
public struct Point
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}
Point[] directions = new Point[]
{
    new Point() {x=0,y=1 },
    new Point() {x=0,y=-1 },
    new Point() {x=1,y=0 },
    new Point() {x=-1,y=0 }
};
```

i have n players, for example 3 but this number is not constant.

i need enumerate all possibile moves into an array.
for example:

```
    player1: up, player2:up, player3:up
    player1: up, player2:up, player3:left
    player1: up, player2:up, player3:right
    player1: up, player2:up, player3:down
    player1: up, player2:left, player3:up
    ....
    ....
```

what is the best way to enumerate all possible moves of all players into an array?

the resulting array must be:

```
item[0] = {up,up,up};
item[1] = {up,up,down};
item[2] = {up,up,left};
item[3] = {up,up,right};
item[4] = {up,down,up};
....
```

please, can you help me?

Comment: Before writing its code, it is related to mathematics. Find the formula then try to Code.

Comment: Where is your code! What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have an enum like

```
enum Move
{
    Up,
    Down,
    Left,
    Right
}
```

A way is to iterate an integer and convert this integer to the base 4. The result will be:

0000 --> 0001 ---> 0002 ---> 0003 --> 0010 --> ... ---> 3333

You can take every digit of the numbers and cast it to the enum value. Here is the resulting method:

```
private static List<Move[]> GetPossibleMoves(int NumberOfPlayers)
{
    int Combination = 0;
    List<Move[]> PossibleMoves = new List<Move[]>();
    while (true)
    {
        List<int> Digits = IntToString(Combination, new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3' })
            .PadLeft(NumberOfPlayers, '0')
            .Select(D => Convert.ToInt32(D.ToString()))
            .ToList();

        if (Digits.Count() > NumberOfPlayers)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Move[] Moves = new Move[NumberOfPlayers];
            for (int Player = 0; Player < NumberOfPlayers; Player++)
            {
                Moves[Player] = (Move)Digits[Player];
            }
            PossibleMoves.Add(Moves);                 
        }
        Combination++;
    }
    return PossibleMoves;
}
```

As helper to convert to the base 4 you can take the method from Dirk Vollmar at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923771/quickest-way-to-convert-a-base-10-number-to-any-base-in-net):

```
private static string IntToString(int value, char[] baseChars)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    int targetBase = baseChars.Length;

    do
    {
        result = baseChars[value % targetBase] + result;
        value = value / targetBase;
    }
    while (value > 0);

    return result;
}
```

The result will be:

> Up, Up, Up, Up
>
> Up, Up, Up, Down
>
> Up, Up, Up, Left
>
> Up, Up, Up, Right
>
> Up, Up, Down, Up
>
> ...
>
> Right, Right, Right Right

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have 4 players and each has a 4 possible moves. A total of 256 combinations. n players, 4 moves => 4^n
Map your moves to numbers
Up - 0,
Down - 1,
Left - 2, 
Right - 3 Then convert the 256(base of 10) to base of 4 and you will get 10000. So Iterate from 0 to 3333 (in base of 4) and extract each number place and map accordingly for each player.
In example a number of 2330 would mean - 1st player - Left, 2nd player - right, 3rd - right, 4th player - up

Answer (score 1):

Using this enum:

```
public enum Direction
{
    Up,
    Down,
    Right,
    Left
}
```

Try to iterate over the enum values using [Enum.GetValues Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues(v=vs.110).aspx) and use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631(v=vs.110).aspx) Linq SelectMany overload(which lets you to create every combination out of two IEnumerables items) to create all the combinations:

```
var options = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Direction)).Cast<Direction>()
              .SelectMany(firstValue => Enum.GetValues(typeof(Direction)).Cast<Direction>(), 
                 (firstValue, secondValue) => new { firstValue, secondValue})
              .SelecyMany(firstValues => Enum.GetValues(typeof(Direction)).Cast<Direction>(), 
                 (firstValues, lastValue) => new {firstValues.firstValue, firstValues.secondValue, lastValue}).ToList();
```

You can also replace the last SelectMany to create a 3 length array as the list item instead the annonymous type, just replace the last line with:

```
(firstValues, lastValue) => new Direction[] {firstValues.firstValue, firstValues.secondValue, lastValue}).ToList();
```