# Find the base of the system where this equation is true: 99 * 99 = 1210

Tags: c#, algorithm

I want to solve this kind of problem:

**I want to find the base of the system where this equation is true: 99 * 99 = 1210.**

This equations seems to be written in the base, more than 10, so it's a bit confusing for me.

For bases, below 10 I am using the following methods in order to convert from Base P to base 10 or vise versa, but for bases above 10, seems that they don't work.

```
static int ConvertToPBase(int numberInTenBase, int P)
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    while (numberInTenBase > 0)
    {
       list.Add((numberInTenBase % P));
       numberInTenBase /= P;
    }

    list.Reverse();
    string x = "";
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        x += item;
    }

    return Convert.ToInt32(x);
}

static int ConvertTo10BaseFromP(int P, int number)
{
    int answer = 0;
    string num = number.ToString();

    for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
    {
        answer = answer * P + Convert.ToInt32(num[i].ToString());
    }

    return answer;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quickest way to convert a base 10 number to any base in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923771/quickest-way-to-convert-a-base-10-number-to-any-base-in-net)

Comment: I also want actual algorithm to solve this problem

Comment: start from base 1 (or 9 in your case) and increase the base until equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, and probably closer to what you were interested in you can try every base until you find one where the equation holds. Pseudo-code below:

```
start-base = 9; lhs = 0; rhs = 0;
repeat {
  # convert to base 10 for arithmetic
  lhs = to-base(from-base('99', start-base), 10) ** 2;
  rhs = to-base(from-base('1210', start-base), 10);

  start-base += 1;
} until lhs == rhs;

print start-base - 1;
```

Note: this does not account for the case where the equation doesn't hold in any base.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve for this directly. Remember, that the positional notation in some base `b` makes use of (integer) powers of `b`. e.g. 1210 in base 10 can be computed using `(1*10)^3 + (2*10)^2 + (1*10)^1 + (0*10)^0`

If you use the base as the variable, you get equations with a variable b to solve for:

```
(9b^1 + 9b^0) * (9b^1 + 9b^0) = 1b^3 + 2b^2 + 1b^1 + 0b^0
```

Comment: I think you need some brackets in your “equation”

Comment: It seems confusing for me.. Should I consider it as ordinary equation? is b^0 = 1 ?  which rule did you use to write this kind of equation?

Comment: aren't brackets needed like this? (9b^1 + 9b^0) * (9b^1 + 9b^0)

Comment: @Shouldnotdownvote Anything raised to the 0 is always 1

Comment: Solving for b gives 81

Comment: I think also 0 and -1 are solutions for the equation, but they clearly don't fit the domain