# Convert integer to base 4 in F#

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I want to convert a given integer into a base 4 string. For eg : In scala,

```
var str: String = Integer.toString(10, 4)
gives the output "22"  ie 2*(4^1) + 2*(4^0) = 10
```

Im having difficulty doing this in F#. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Does this provide an answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10981113/14134059 Often with fairly commonly computing questions in F# there is an adequate C# solution that can be readily adapted by straight translation.

Comment: Huh, I was going to say System.Convert, but it only works with base 2, 8, 10, and 16. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?view=netcore-3.1#System_Convert_ToString_System_Int32_System_Int32_

Answer (score 0):

```
let intToDigits baseN value : int list =
    let rec loop num digits =
        let q = num / baseN
        let r = num % baseN
        if q = 0 then 
            r :: digits 
        else 
            loop q (r :: digits)

    loop value []

254
|> intToDigits 16
|> List.fold (fun acc x -> acc + x.ToString("X")) ""
|> printfn "%s"

254
|> intToDigits 4
|> List.fold (fun acc x -> acc + x.ToString()) ""
|> printfn "%s"
```

This outputs `FE` for the base-16 conversion and `3332` for the base-4 conversion.  Note that `ToString("X")` works for up to base 16, so it could be used for the base-4 conversion too.

I adapted this int based solution from [Stuart Lang's bigint example](https://stu.dev/bigint-to-string-in-any-base-fsharp) (which uses `bigint.DivRem` rather than integer operators).